# Indesign: Text -Trouble replacing existing text or inserting small object

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, selections

I need to replace some of the text in this text box. It will allow me to triple-click the entire line, but I can't just select part of the text to replace an e-mail address or do other editing. Any thoughts? (I'm confused with the areas that InDesign is displaying and which I've highlighted.)

[image: Screenshot of text issue]

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl-Y or Edit Menu "Edit Story In Editor" so you can see the text in word-processor mode instead of wysiwyg. (Is it auto-generated text by any chance?)

Comment: The text is not auto-generated. The story editor looks basic, with [Basic Paragraph] next to the two lines (the 1, 2, etc. are superscript)

1Company Name, address, Canada and other company, University of something, Anytown, Canada; 2Company Name Inc., Anytown2, Canada; 3Company Name West, West Anytown, Australia
Corresponding author:  author@something.com

Comment: [Basic Paragraph] is telling you what paragraph tag is applied to the text. So are you unable to edit the text in the Story Editor? Can you select individual words with the mouse or the (shift/control) arrow keys? ... (Check for the sticky alt/shift/control keys too.)

Comment: Post your InDesign file and I will autopsy it. The highlights in your screen shot almost look like you have a separate text object other than the text box in question: text in the screen shot does not match text in your comment.